# How can I block QTableWidget signals after disabling the table?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, qtablewidget, qtablewidgetitem

I have a python QTableWidget populated with 4 columns. Selecting any of the columns runs the qTableWidget.cellClicked() signal, which then highlights the entire row, and runs a bunch of code.

```
self._qTableWidget.cellClicked.connect(self.cellClicked)

def cellClicked(self, row, column):
   """
      Handle cell clicked signal.
   """
   self._qTableWidget.setDisabled(True)
   qTableWidgetItem = self._qTableWidget.item(row, column)
   if qTableWidgetItem is None:
      return
   else:
      # ***RUNS SOME CODE***
      pass
   self._qTableWidget.setEnabled(True)
```

In the code, I want to disable the QTableWidget from accepting any clicks until after the code runs, then enable the QTableWidget (which I have tried by using setDisabled()/setEnabled()).

However if you click a cell, the table is disabled correctly, but you can still click on cells in the table. When the table is enabled again, it runs the cellClicked() signal again on the QTableWidgetItem you clicked on while the table was disabled.

I have tried using the following:

```
self._qTableWidget.blockSignals(True)
self._qTableWidget.blockSignals(False)
```

```python
self._qTableWidget.cellClicked.disconnect(self.cellClicked)
self._qTableWidget.cellClicked.connect(self.cellClicked)
```

```python
self.setAllCellItemFlags(QtCore.Qt.NoItemFlags)

def setAllCellItemFlags(self, flag):
   """
      Sets all QTableWidgetItem flags
   """
   for row in range(self._qTableWidget.rowCount()):
      for column in range(self._qTableWidget.columnCount()):
         qTableWidgetItem = self._qTableWidget.item(row, column)
         qTableWidgetItem.setFlags(flag)
```

Comment: Whatever is executed within `cellClicked` will temporarily block the event loop until it returns, and if the table widget is disabled it will **not** emit the `cellClicked` signal, so you're probably doing something wrong in the `RUNS SOME CODE` block which prevents proper event handling (and updating of the widget, which is enabled but not redrawn as such). You're not doing some thread related processing there, right? Please show what that block does by providing a [mre].

Comment: As V.K. correctly points out, if the code is blocking and gets a lot of time for processing, the queued events will still be processed when control returns to the main event loop. Note that if you need to do complex computations, you should consider a QThread subclass (or a QObject moved to a QThread), disable the widget, start the thread, and connect its result signal to a function that properly updates and re-enables the table. This will also prevent unexpected behavior if the user tries to click somewhere else or types something in the meantime. Btw, for future reference, provide a [mre].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what probably happens in your code:

1. first click arrives and it emits signal
2. in the connected slot you disable (or disconnect) signals
3. you start your code and while it is running it blocks the event loop in the main thread
4. meanwhile another mouse click comes, it creates mouse click event but it is put to waiting queue waiting for the event loop to be able to process it
5. after a while your lengthy code gets finished and you re-enable (or re-connect) the signals
6. the event loop gets unblocked and processes the waiting mouse event
7. as response to the click event another signal gets emitted and connected slot gets run again, i.e. going to step 2...

As you can see, the second click gets processed AFTER the signal gets re-enabled. This is the root cause of your problem. What you need to do is to re-enable the signals AFTER the event loop processes the waiting mouse click (or mouse clicks).

The easiest solution would be to call `QApplication.processEvents(QEventLoop.AllEvents, 0)` just before you re-enable the signals. This will cause all click events to be processed, i.e. ignored because the signals will still be disabled at that moment. Please read the documentation about this overload of the method which processes also posted (not yet queued) events. In contrast to the other overload without `ms` argument, which processes only already queued events. If value `0` is not sufficient, then experiment with a bit longer time delays, e.g. 100 ms.

Comment: What you're saying is almost certainly the issue. Unfortunately, QApplication.processEvents() does not seem to stop the waiting queue from processing the mouse click events when I place it right before the "self._qTableWidget.setEnabled(True)"

Comment: OK, this is strange. Maybe try to experiment a little bit with the overload `https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcoreapplication.html#processEvents-1` which has the additional `ms` parameter. Try setting e.g. 100 ms, maybe the events are posted (i.e. on the way, not necessarily in the queue). The additional time will allow for posted events to be handled. If this does not help, then my answer was probably wrong and the root cause is something else.

Comment: Setting the `ms` parameter in the overloaded function has fixed the problem.

Comment: I updated the answer so that it reflects your finding and so that it can be used by others. What value of `ms` have you used? Did it work with 0 ms? Or did you need to set longer time?

Comment: I originally started with your suggested 100, which fixed the problem. I then moved it down until the issue started happening again. The lowest I can set it is ~30

Comment: Maybe you can try another experiment: try calling the method with `0` waiting time. And then try to call it once more. What could happen (I am not definitely sure about it, I am just guessing) is that during the first call, the mouse events will be created and queued. And during the second run they will be processed. Could you try it? This would solve the problem with setting "arbitrary long" time.

Comment: @Pooliey it would *really* help to know what you're doing in that code block, as I'm under the impression that this is caused by a wrong implementation, and requiring the `processEvents(ms)` overload in the UI usually means that something else is (or is done) wrong. Note that you could even delay the enabled state (or signal re-connection) using a basic singleShot QTimer.